# ¿Suma de distintos items en una lista?

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist

Estoy entrando al mundo de programación java y android, la verdad es que estoy muy verde en ambas y me he estancado con este programa, la idea es que el usuario pueda introducir sus ingresos y gastos en el mes y con un boton vea cuanto le queda de acuerdo a sus movimientos. Si alguien le puede echar un ojo y orientarme hacia donde está el error lo agradecería. Hasta ahora pinta bien los movimientos en la lista pero a la hora de hacer la operación, realmente no estoy obteniendo los datos de la lista y solo devuelve un valor de 0.

Gracias.

```
private ArrayList<Movimientos> listaMovimientos;
private ArrayAdapter<Movimientos> adaptador;
private Object Movimientos;
TextView tvSaldo = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btIngreso = findViewById(R.id.btIngreso);
    btIngreso.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button btEgreso = findViewById(R.id.btEgreso);
    btEgreso.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button btSaldoTotal = findViewById(R.id.btSaldoTotal);
    btSaldoTotal.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button btBorrar = findViewById(R.id.btBorrar);
    btBorrar.setOnClickListener(this);

    listaMovimientos = new ArrayList<>();
    adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaMovimientos);
    ListView ltMovimientos = findViewById(R.id.ltMovimientos);
    ltMovimientos.setAdapter(adaptador);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    EditText etMontos = null;
    EditText etDetalle = null;
    String detalle;
    float egreso;
    float ingreso;

    switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btIngreso:

            etMontos = findViewById(R.id.etMontos);
            etDetalle = findViewById(R.id.etDetalle);

            if(etMontos.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.mIntroduzcaMonto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }else if (etMontos.getText().toString().equals(0)){
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.mIntroduzcaMonto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (etDetalle.getText().toString().equals("")){

                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.mCampoObligatoiro, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            detalle = etDetalle.getText().toString();
            ingreso = Float.parseFloat(etMontos.getText().toString());

            Movimientos movimiento = new Movimientos(detalle, ingreso);

            listaMovimientos.add(movimiento);
            adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

            etMontos.setText("");
            etDetalle.setText("");
            etMontos.requestFocus();

            break;

        case R.id.btEgreso:

            etMontos = findViewById(R.id.etMontos);
            etDetalle = findViewById(R.id.etDetalle);

            if(etMontos.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(this, "El campo debe contener un valor válido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (etMontos.getText().toString().equals(0)){
                Toast.makeText(this, "El valor debe ser superior a 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (etDetalle.getText().toString().equals("")){

                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.mCampoObligatoiro, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            detalle = etDetalle.getText().toString();
            egreso = Float.parseFloat(etMontos.getText().toString());

            Movimientos movimiento2 = new Movimientos(detalle, egreso);

            listaMovimientos.add(movimiento2);
            adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

            etMontos.setText("");
            etDetalle.setText("");
            etMontos.requestFocus();

            break;

        case R.id.btSaldoTotal:

            saldoTotal();

            break;

        case R.id.btBorrar:

            tvSaldo.setText("");
            listaMovimientos.clear();
            adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

        default:
            break;
    }

}

public void saldoTotal() {

    float auxI = 0;
    float auxE = 0;
    float saldoTotal = 0;

    for (Movimientos movimientos : listaMovimientos){

        auxI += movimientos.gettipoMovimiento();
    }

    for (Movimientos movimiento2 : listaMovimientos ){

        auxE += movimiento2.gettipoMovimiento();
    }

    saldoTotal = auxI - auxE;
    String stringTotal = Float.toString(saldoTotal);

    tvSaldo = findViewById(R.id.tvSaldo);
    tvSaldo.setText(getString(R.string.mSumaMovimientos)+ ": " + stringTotal);
}
```

}

```
package com.tokioschool.ahorrapp;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

class Movimientos {

    private String detalle;
    private float tipoMovimiento;

public Movimientos (String detalle, float tipoMovimiento){

    this.detalle = detalle;
    this.tipoMovimiento = tipoMovimiento;
}

    public String getDetalle() {

    return detalle;
}

    public float gettipoMovimiento() {

        return tipoMovimiento;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "(" + detalle + ") " + tipoMovimiento;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te recomiendo que completes el [tour] de bienvenida para ganar tu primera medalla y comprender mejor cómo hacer buenas preguntas. Esto no quita que la pregunta que has hecho está bien: has aportado el código necesario para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios errores en el código, vamos a repasarlos...

- Cuando haces un ingreso o egreso tienes estas comprobaciones:

  ```
      if (etMontos.getText().toString().equals("")){
          Toast.makeText(this, R.string.mIntroduzcaMonto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return;
      }else if (etMontos.getText().toString().equals(0)){
          Toast.makeText(this, R.string.mIntroduzcaMonto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return;
      }
  ```

  Aunque no es un error, la primera de ellas podrías sustituirla por

  ```
  if (etMontos.getText().toString().isEmpty()){ ...
  ```

  Y en la segunda sí hay un error:

  ```
  }else if (etMontos.getText().toString().equals(0)){
  ```

Usar `String.equals` con `0` siempre devolverá false, porque `0` es un Integer y por tanto nunca será igual al String `"0"`.

- En ambos casos haces algo similar:

  1. Ingreso

     ```
     detalle = etDetalle.getText().toString();
     ingreso = Float.parseFloat(etMontos.getText().toString());
     Movimientos movimiento = new Movimientos(detalle, ingreso);
     ```
  2. Egreso

     ```
     detalle = etDetalle.getText().toString();
     egreso = Float.parseFloat(etMontos.getText().toString());
     Movimientos movimiento2 = new Movimientos(detalle, egreso);
     ```

  Es decir, no distingues entre ambos, realmente: no te aseguras de que que el ingreso sea positivo y el egreso negativo, por ejemplo. Otra opción es añadir un campo que sea *realmente* el tipo de operación: Es decir, podrías tener algo como

  ```
  class Movimiento {

      private String detalle;
      private double cantidad;
      private boolean ingreso;
      //getters y setters
  }
  ```

  Y de ese modo tener un boolean que te diga si se ha de sumar o de restar.
- Finalmente, cuando intentas hacer los cálculos tienes:

  ```
  for (Movimientos movimientos : listaMovimientos){

      auxI += movimientos.gettipoMovimiento();
  }

  for (Movimientos movimiento2 : listaMovimientos ){

      auxE += movimiento2.gettipoMovimiento();
  }
  ```

  Es decir, haces dos veces la misma suma de movimientos, porque no tienes nada que te permita filtrarlos o un signo que te permita diferenciar ingresos de egresos... y al final `auxE` es igual que `auxI` **siempre** y, por tanto, la resta siempre es 0.

Comment: Vaya muchas gracias por tus comentarios Pablo, bastante puntual y de utilidad. Solo a manera de aclaratoria y para ver si entendí lo que me quisiste decir: Debo declarar este valor booleano en la clase que indica si es ingreso u egreso y llamar a este en la función "saldoTotal()"?.. De resto la manera que implemente para recorrer la lista y tratar de hacer la operación, esta medianamente bien?